2008 Chevy Uplander rear driver caliper and front passenger caliper keeps locking up
I have a stiff brake pedal. my driver side rear caliper keeps locking up. My front passenger caliper keeps locking up. How can I fix this?

Welcome to the site. What servicing have you had done on the brakes, or done yourself?

Would you please click EDIT under your question and add some details about "locking up"? Does the vehicle suddenly leave skid marks while driving? Are the brakes overheating? Or is the only  trouble that when you raise the wheels off the ground, you can't turn them, but the vehicle drives OK? More details so we can help you.

We had a bmw in months back with a similar concern. The main things to look at here are the ABS hydraulic unit or control module and/ or if this vehicle has a combination, metering, or proportioning valve that controls front/rear brake system pressure.
